# Meta Data for Custom Post Type not saving

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, post-meta

I'm in the process of building a custom plugin, and I'm having trouble saving meta data for the custom post type. The boxes display correctly in the editor, but when I click Publish or Save Draft, the values I've entered are not retained.

I've pasted snippets of my code below. I've followed a few tutorials, and looked through several questions here, but it looks like I've followed everything correctly, and I can't figure out where I went wrong. I'm sure it's something obvious.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Custom Post Type

```
// Register the Jobs post type
function fg_registerJobsPostType() {
    // Floodgate Jobs Post Type
    $fg_postType = 'fg_job';

    $jobsLabels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Floodgate Jobs', 'post type general name', '' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Floodgate Job', 'post type singular name', '' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Floodgate Jobs', 'admin menu', '' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Floodgate Job', 'add new on admin bar', '' ),
        'add_new'            => __( 'Add New', 'Floodgate Job', '' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Job', '' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Job', '' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Job', '' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Job', '' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Jobs', '' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Jobs', '' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Jobs:', '' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Jobs found.', '' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Jobs found in Trash.', '' ),
    );

    $jobsArgs = array(
        'labels'             => $jobsLabels,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'fg_job' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => 5,
        'supports'           => array( 'editor', 'custom-fields' )        
    );

    register_post_type( 'fg_job', $jobsArgs );
}
add_action( 'init', 'fg_registerJobsPostType' );
```

And The Metaboxes

```
// Register the Jobs Metaboxes
function fg_registerJobsMetabox() {
    /* Add meta boxes on the 'add_meta_boxes' hook. */
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'fg_addJobMetaboxes' );

    /* Save post meta on the 'save_post' hook. */
    add_action( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'fg_saveJobsMeta', 10, 2);
}
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'fg_registerJobsMetabox' );
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'fg_registerJobsMetabox' );

// Build the display components for the Jobs Metaboxes
function fg_addJobMetaboxes() {
    add_meta_box(
        'fg_jobDesc',      // Unique ID
        esc_html__( 'Job Description', 'Business Cards' ),    // Title
        'fg_jobDescMetabox',   // Callback function
        'fg_job',         // Admin page (or post type)
        'side',         // Context
        'default'         // Priority
    );

    add_meta_box(
        'fg_jobStatus',      // Unique ID
        esc_html__( 'Job Status', 'Printing' ),    // Title
        'fg_jobStatusMetabox',   // Callback function
        'fg_job',         // Admin page (or post type)
        'side',         // Context
        'default'         // Priority
    );

    add_meta_box(
        'fg_jobDueDate',      // Unique ID
        esc_html__( 'Due Date', '' ),    // Title
        'fg_jobDueDateMetabox',   // Callback function
        'fg_job',         // Admin page (or post type)
        'side',         // Context
        'default'         // Priority
    );

    add_meta_box(
        'fg_jobPriority',      // Unique ID
        esc_html__( 'Job Priority', '' ),    // Title
        'fg_jobPriorityMetabox',   // Callback function
        'fg_job',         // Admin page (or post type)
        'side',         // Context
        'default'         // Priority
    );
}
```

And the save functions

```
function fg_verifyMetaNonce($metaKey) {
    return  (isset($_POST[$metaKey . '_nonce']) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[$metaKey . '_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)));
}

function fg_saveMetaData($postID, $metaKey, $newMetaValue) {
    /* Get the meta value of the custom field key. */
    $metaValue = get_post_meta( $postID, $metaKey, true );

    /* If a new meta value was added and there was no previous value, add it. */
    if ( $newMetaValue && '' == $metaValue )
        update_post_meta( $postID, $metaKey, $newMetaValue, true );

    /* If the new meta value does not match the old value, update it. */
    elseif ( $newMetaValue && $newMetaValue != $metaValue )
        update_post_meta( $postID, $metaKey, $newMetaValue );

    /* If there is no new meta value but an old value exists, delete it. */
    elseif ( '' == $newMetaValue && $metaValue )
        delete_post_meta( $postID, $metaKey, $metaValue );
}


// Save the Jobs Metadata
function fg_saveJobsMeta($postID, $post) {
    /* Get the post type object. */
    $postType = get_post_type_object( $post->postType );

/* Check if the current user has permission to edit the post. */
if ( !current_user_can( $postType->cap->edit_post, $postID ) )
    return $postID;

    // Save the Job Description
    $metaKey = 'fg_jobDesc';

        /* Verify the nonce before proceeding. */
        if ( verifyMetaNonce($metaKey) )
            return $postID;

        /* Get the posted data and sanitize it for use as an HTML class. */
        $jobDesc = ( isset( $_POST[$metaKey] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST[$metaKey] ) : '' );

    fg_saveMetaData($postID, $metaKey, $jobDesc);

    // Save the Job Status
    $metaKey = 'fg_jobStatus';

        /* Verify the nonce before proceeding. */
        if ( verifyMetaNonce($metaKey) )
            return $postID;

        /* Get the posted data and sanitize it for use as an HTML class. */
        $jobStatus = ( isset( $_POST[$metaKey] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST[$metaKey] ) : '' );

        fg_saveMetaData($postID, $metaKey, $jobStatus);

    // Save the Job Description
    $metaKey = 'fg_jobDueDate';

        /* Verify the nonce before proceeding. */
        if ( verifyMetaNonce($metaKey) )
            return $postID;

        /* Get the posted data and sanitize it for use as an HTML class. */
        $jobDueDate = ( isset( $_POST[$metaKey] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST[$metaKey] ) : '' );

        fg_saveMetaData($postID, $metaKey, $jobDueDate);

    // Save the Job Description
    $metaKey = 'fg_jobPriority';

        /* Verify the nonce before proceeding. */
        if ( verifyMetaNonce($metaKey) )
            return $postID;

        /* Get the posted data and sanitize it for use as an HTML class. */
        $jobPriority = ( isset( $_POST[$metaKey] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST[$metaKey] ) : '' );

        fg_saveMetaData($postID, $metaKey, $jobPriority);
}
```

Comment: I tested your code on my side. There is so much bugs in your code that I stopped fixing after the first six, and believe me, there are still about 20 left, no jokes. You should set debug to true in wp-config, fix errors according, and if your code then still does not work after all the bug fixes, repost and explain where your code fails.

Comment: Have a read [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to debug wordpress

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Kudos for making the effort, and I don't blame you for giving up. I kept trying after posting the question, and realized how far off I was. Kind of embarrassing, actually.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the debug options too. To this point, I've been working on things simple enough that a well placed var_dump() was sufficient to resolve issues. This is my first foray into something more robust. After this mess, I started to look for a better debugging option. You saved me a lot of time. Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm glad I could point you in the right direction. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments on the question indicated, this was basically a pile of garbage (my words, not theirs). There are a number of typos and inverted boolean checks. It was kind of a nightmare.

I managed to get the code working, and I don't like unanswered questions, so I wanted to work through the bugs from the top down and point out the solution that I ended up with.

---

### Problem Area One

The first issue exists in registering the metaboxes:

```
// Register the Jobs Metaboxes
function fg_registerJobsMetabox() {
    /* Add meta boxes on the 'add_meta_boxes' hook. */
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'fg_addJobMetaboxes' );

    /* Save post meta on the 'save_post' hook. */
    add_action( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'fg_saveJobsMeta', 10, 2); // <- THIS IS THE ERROR
}
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'fg_registerJobsMetabox' );
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'fg_registerJobsMetabox' );
```

In this case, the `add_action()` call is incorrect. When using the `wp_insert_post_data` hook, the function parameters of my `fg_saveJobsMeta()` function were coming back with incorrect values.

Switching this to `add_action( 'save_post', 'fg_saveJobsMeta', 10, 2)` resolved this error

---

### Problem Area Two

The next problem exists in the `fg_saveJobsMeta($postID, $post)` function:

```
function fg_saveJobsMeta($postID, $post) {
    /* Get the post type object. */
    $postType = get_post_type_object( $post->postType ); // <- THIS IS THE ERROR

    /* Check if the current user has permission to edit the post. */
    if ( !current_user_can( $postType->cap->edit_post, $postID ) )
        return $postID;
    [...]
}
```

the value of `$postType` **was always being set to null**, because `$post->postType` is incorrect. This should change to `$post->post_type` as `post_type` is the field on the actual post object.

---

### Problem Area Three

The next issue is a little further down in the `fg_saveJobsMeta()` function:

```
// Save the Job Description
$metaKey = 'fg_jobDesc';

    /* Verify the nonce before proceeding. */
    if ( verifyMetaNonce($metaKey) ) // <- THIS IS THE ERROR
        return $postID;

    /* Get the posted data and sanitize it for use as an HTML class. */
    $jobDesc = ( isset( $_POST[$metaKey] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST[$metaKey] ) : '' );

fg_saveMetaData($postID, $metaKey, $jobDesc);
```

There are two problems here.

- `verifyMetaNonce($metaKey)` is the incorrect function.

The correct function call is `fg_verifyMetaNonce($metaKey)`. The function name is prefixed to reduce the chances of collision with other plugins and/or themes.

- The boolean check is backwards.

If `fg_verifyMetaNonce($metaKey)` returns `true` (meaning we have a valid nonce value), the function will return the `$postID` and exit, but it should save.

The correct call in this case would be `if (!fg_verifyMetaNonce($metaKey)`. This will only exit the save process if the nonce value *fails* validation.

These errors were repeated several times (once for each of the custom fields I identified).

---

### Problem Area Four

In solving the issue, I discovered that I had additional problems in code that I did not post on the original question.

There were a few errors in setting up the actual metabox UI elements (once again, repeated for each custom field). I copied one of the fields below:

```
// Generate the Job Description Metaboxes
function fg_jobDescMetabox() { // <- ERROR HERE
    wp_nonce_field( 'updating_job_meta', 'fg_jobDesc_nonce'); ?> // <- ERROR HERE

    <p>
        // ERROR HERE
        <input class="widefat" type="text" name="fg_jobDesc" id="fg_jobDesc"
        value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fg_jobDesc', true ) ); ?>" />
    </p>
<?php }
```

The correct code is as follows:

```
// Generate the Job Description Metaboxes
function fg_jobDescMetabox($object, $box) {
// ^ This function actually receives two arguments.
    wp_nonce_field( 'updating_job_meta', 'fg_jobDesc_nonce', true); ?>
    // ^ The wp_nonce_field() call needed a third boolean argument
    //   Without this argument, the nonce value was never set on the request.

    <p>
        <input class="widefat" type="text" name="fg_jobDesc" id="fg_jobDesc"
        value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'fg_jobDesc', true ) ); ?>" />
        // ^ the global `$post` variable is null here, so using it did me no good.
        //   I need to use the $object parameter passed into the function instead. 
    </p>
<?php }
```

As mentioned above, this issue was repeated for each of my custom fields, so I needed to fix it in several places.

---

I've looked through the horribly bugged code and have compared it to my working version several times now. I believe that this covers all of the issues and differences between the two files.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer. I must congratulate you on the excellent structure of your answer. +1. It is answers like this that keeps this site constructive